# Am I a bad user if I have more questions than answers?

Tags: discussion

I just had a shower thought, I thought that I am a bad user for asking more questions than I have answered, I have only answered 5 questions and I think that makes me a bad user, Am I right? Should I try to answer more questions?

Also...Sorry for my hostile behaviour...I had some problems and I was not right, Gomenasai.

Comment: You're the best sort of user! At least for me, I'm all answers and no questions, without people like you I'd have nothing to answer.

Comment: Good questions are at least as difficult to come up with as good answers.

Answer (score 29):

The general answer is **no, you're not a bad user for posting more questions than answers.**

Without questions, there would be nothing to answer. *This isn't Jeopardy* where we give the answer first and only then figure out what the question is. (Well... exceptions may apply, but that's the general idea.)

Different people participate in different ways. Some ask questions. Some answer questions. Some edit posts for clarity, spelling, and so on. Some spend a lot of time in the review queues. Some might do little more than vote posts up or down.

And you know what? *It's all fine!* Every user who somehow contributes positively to the site is equally welcome. It doesn't matter *how* you are contributing, as long as you do so *positively*.

Answer (score 11):

Absolutely **NO**!

There's an old bromide regarding Catholic missions: *Some give by going to the Missions. Some go by giving to the Missions. Without both there are no Missions.* This is entirely apropos to this situation.

I've written 139 answers and 1 question; you've written 1 answer and 10 questions. I see no more problem with members who only ask questions than I do with those who only answer.

As a matter of fact, for a member like me who only answers, you, who only ask, are a perfect kind of member of this community!

Answer (score 7):

If I have to answer based on my experience, there are several flavors of users, each with a particular preference.

Some prefer to comment on questions, trying to improve clarity, some are focused on a single topic question, some are more dedicated to answering, some other... well, I think you got what I mean.

Each of them brings contribution to the community, so I don't feel like labeling them as "bad users".

From another point of view, if *ab axurdo* everybody would only answer questions, who would post them?

As long as one sticks to the be nice policy and brings valuable contribution to the community I dare to say they are welcome.

Answer (score 4):

I' ve just arrived and I feel the same. But with some patience and time I'm sure I'll manage to find some questions that need my knowledge on various subject. Time is important, patience too, and every bit of knowledge is always accepted.

Comment: Hear hear! Also, welcome to the forum!

Comment: yay, thank you. I have lot to learn but I hope to get a good starting point on the meta :)

Comment: Also, don't be afraid to answer old questions (and there's no need to point out a question's age, either). A good answer to an old question, where you have the time to really look up all the facts and articulate everything clearly, can make a great addition to the site.

Answer (score 0):

If you could be writing useful or helpful answers, but are not, then some could possibly consider you a “bad user”.  Of course, your reasons for doing so are your own, and they might mitigate any potential reasons for dislike from the other people here would want to read your answers.

Whether you should answer or not depends on whether you are willing to hazard testing your information and knowledge and skills for any merit.
Only post an answer if you are willing defend it, improve it, and … all that.  Don't do it simply to balance your ratio.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO Questions are actually harder to formulate than answers. If you can ask interesting questions within the format here, that aren't duplicates, more power to you. I think questions take more practice to get right than answers...

There are lots of different kinds of users on here--in other communities a balance of questions and answers is a thing, but not here. So ask away!!! And don't worry too much if you don't have the format down at first, some of mine have been rejected, and rightly so--I've had duplicates, I've asked in the wrong format and so on. You have to consider far more in framing a question, that it's narrow enough, that it's not largely opinion-based, that it's been decently researched and considered before being asked, and so on.